# How could the universe be hyperbolic if hyperbolic space isn't symmetrical?

Tags: cosmology, universe, curvature, geometry, visualization

In the 2-D projections of the shape of the universe shown [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/End_of_universe.jpg/413px-End_of_universe.jpg), we see that the flat universe and the spherical universe are perfectly symmetrical, so any triangle drawn anywhere on them will be the same.  However, the hyperbolic universe appears to only be symmetrical on two axes, so any triangle drawn anywhere on it will not necessarily be the same as some identical triangle drawn somewhere else on it.  This implies that the hyperbolic universe would have a center and that shapes would have different dimensions at different locations in the universe.  Is this the case in this scenario, or is the apparent lack of symmetry an artifact of this being a projection of a 3-D space onto a 2-D image?  Or is there something else that I am missing?

Comment: Don't take these pictures literally ;) Hyperbolic space has all necessary symmetries to satisfy the established posulates of  relativity.

Comment: And yes - you are tricking yourself by thinking the number of dimensions is 2 anywhere. Think of hyperbolic space as a continuous time-series of (1D) "chains" of 2D hyperbolic surfaces like that on the picture.

Comment: We live on a spherical planet, though that doesn't mean that when you have to take into account the curvature of the planet when you drive 10 kilometers to your friend's house.  I doubt very much that if there were curvature that we'd be able to tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to draw an accurate picture of a 2D hyperbolic surface, because such a surface cannot be embedded into a 3D euclidean space; this is known as [Hilbert's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_theorem_%28differential_geometry%29). The saddle surface in the figure is just an approximation, and serves as an illustration that every point on a hyperbolic surface is a saddle point.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing hyperbolic space with the hyperbolic paraboloid. The hyperbolic paraboloid does not have constant curvature, being the farthest from zero, as you described, in the center of the saddle.

Hyperbolic space is indeed "symmetrical" (homogeneous and isotropic). Standard models for the space are the Poincaré ball, Klein ball, upper half-space, and hyperboloid. Each has its own advantages and disadvantages for visualization and computation.

In the Poincaré ball and upper half space models, straight lines look curved but angles appear correct. In the Klein ball model, straight lines look straight but angles look different from their true measurements. In the hyperboloid model, one requires an additional spacial dimension to embed it. One can find images of these illustrating how hyperbolic symmetry works, but each requires some imagination since our way of perceiving them is Euclidean.